# Is there a way to have different expiration for different idempotency records in aws-lambda-powertools-java?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-powertools

Is there a way to configure different expiration time for different idempotency records? In the docs, it is possible to use `@Idempotent` on individual methods which stores the method response as idempotent record. If I want to use this annotation on 3 methods in my lambda, is there any way to have different expiration config for each of these methods? Or is this a global config?

And if possible, how to achieve it?

Link : https://awslabs.github.io/aws-lambda-powertools-java/utilities/idempotency/#customizing-the-default-behavior

Answer (score 0):

As of now, the ExpirationInSeconds parameter is "global" for all idempotent methods. There's no way to have different for each of them.
You can open an [issue](https://github.com/aws-powertools/powertools-lambda-java/issues) explaining your use case and we'll be happy to have a look at it.